# Can I determine at runtime the available NLS character sets?

Tags: linux, mount, character-encoding

I can find the list of the kernel's supported filesystem types in `/proc/filesystems`.

Is there a way to determine which character sets I'm able to use with the `mount` options `iocharset` or `nls`, other than by attempting to mount a filesystem?

Ideally, I'd like the list in a Bash array, so I can use it for command completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLS character sets are provided as [modules with names starting with `nls_`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14/source/fs/nls/nls_base.c#L291). To determine the supported character sets, you can thus:

- look for builtin character sets in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`:

  ```sh
   grep kernel/fs/nls/nls_ /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin
  ```
- list the available modules in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls`:

  ```sh
   echo /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls/nls_*
  ```

To get a usable list, we need to extract the charset names from the module filepaths:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
charsets=($(grep ^kernel/fs/nls/nls_ /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin)
         /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs/nls/nls_*)
charsets=("${charsets[@]##*/nls_}"); charsets=("${charsets[@]%.ko}")
```

This yields a list suitable for command completion, if we exclude `nls_base.ko` (which doesn't implement an actual encoding):

```sh
$ compgen -W "${charsets[*]}" -X base -- 
ascii
cp1250
cp1251
cp1255
cp437
cp737
cp775
cp850
cp852
cp855
cp857
cp860
cp861
cp862
cp863
cp864
cp865
cp866
cp869
cp874
cp932
cp936
cp949
cp950
euc-jp
iso8859-13
iso8859-14
iso8859-15
iso8859-1
iso8859-2
iso8859-3
iso8859-4
iso8859-5
iso8859-6
iso8859-7
iso8859-9
koi8-r
koi8-ru
koi8-u
utf8
```